# Iterarting over array of objects and get unique values of each object

Tags: javascript, vue.js, object

I have this variable inside data():

```
jsonStatham: {
  "uniqueOne": {
    "field1": "",
    "field2": "",
    "field3": "",
    "field4": "",
    "field5": "",
    "freeTextArea": ""
  },
  "uniqueTwo": {
    "field1": "",
    "field2": "",
    "field3":"",
    "field4":"",
    "field5":"",
    "freeTextArea":""
  },
  "uniqueThree": {
    "field1": "",
    "field2": "",
    "freeTextArea": ""
  }
},
```

What I want is to check if a value from this input field:

```
<input type="text" name="platform" placeholder="Platform" id="platform" v-model="platform" required/>
```

is matching one of the keys of "jsonStatham" (uniqueOne/Two/Three) and then push the keys of the matching key into an array. so if the input === uniqueOne, so this array:

```
inputFields: [

],
```

Will look like this: **inputFields["field1","field2","field3","field4","field5"]**

That's what I tried:

```
appendFields() {

      for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(this.jsonStatham)) {
        if(this.brand === this.jsonStatham[key]){
          //console.log("Brand =>", this.brand)
        }
        //console.log(`${key}: ${value}`);
        this.inputFields.push({
          [key]:value
        })
      }
      //console.log("ALL input Fields: \n",this.inputFields)
    },
```

What I get in inputFields is "uniqueOne","uniqueTwo","uniqueThree"

Comment: it's not clear what's branch?

Comment: I think you need to provide more code and clarity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if (this.jsonStatham.hasOwnProperty(this.brand)) {
  this.inputFields.push(...Object.keys(this.jsonStatham[this.brand]));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

this should do the trick:

1. Condition:

```
if(Object.keys(this.jsonStatham).includes(this.brand) )
```

this will be **True** array ["uniqueOne","uniqueTwo","uniqueThree", ..etc]  will include this.brand

2. Pushing to array:

```
this.inputFields.push(...Object.keys(value))
```

Comment: Do my If condition is good? I dont think so

Comment: I don't know what brand can be? :thinking

Comment: Brand is an input field which i enter for example "uniqueOne", if it's match for any of the objects keys, i should see it in console log

Comment: Ohhhhhhhhhhh my bad

Comment: @OsherRevach no worries just updated the code with correct condition, please let me know if that works

Comment: Thanks a lot bro, Iv'e got my answer